# NullReferenceException when trying to do a Join between two Xml Documents

Tags: c#, xml, linq, join, nullreferenceexception

I have an `Xml` document that looks something like this (It contains more parents and children that the shown):

```
<item cid="0x12e3">
    <item cid="0x1310">
        <item cid="0x158b">
            <item luid="2001"/>
            <item luid="2002"/>
        </item>
        <item cid="0x13313">
            <item luid="2001"/>
            <item luid="2002"/>
        </item>
        ... 
    </item>
</item>
```

and Also I have an `Xml` document with some properties like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<EditorRule>
     <Properties>
         <Property name="Comment" luid="2001"/>
         ...
     </Properties>
</EditorRule>
```

Now, I'm doing a `Join` between the two files to `Select` the `XElements` from the `first xml` that are found on the `Second xml`:

```
(from element in Element.Elements().Elements().Elements()
            join property in propertiesFromFile on element.Attribute("luid").Value equals property.Luid 
            select new IpjItem(element));
```

This works fine, and when I Iterate over this `IEnumerable` it prints the `Name="Comment"` and so on.

My problem is that it only works for the first `XElement.` So, going back to the `first Xml`. It only prints the `Children` from the Node with `cid = 0x158b`. After its done with that Element it throws the `NullReferenceException` and does not go to to the one with the `cid = 0x13313`. Why is this happening?

Thanks!

Comment: `Element.Elements().Elements().Elements()` !?

Comment: Yes. That is definitely my problem...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes. As `@Selman22` alarmly inferred, my problem was in `Element.Elements()`. Also I added a better `Where` clause to check if the attribute existed.

```
return (from element in Element.Elements()
            where element.Attribute("luid") != null
            join property in RuleEditorXml.Properties on element.Attribute("luid").Value equals property.Luid
            select new IpjItem(element, Parent));
```